Login with Cypress to an Angular app which uses Azure B2C
We have an Angular app where the user is authenticated using Azure B2C.
For E2E testing we use cypress. When authenticating with cypress we didn't want to use the usual login flow as they advise against it (see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Visiting-external-sites).
So instead, we sent an ROPC (Resource Owner Password Flow) request to get the corresponding tokens and avoid the login-redirect by doing something like this:
Step 1) Get tokens from Azure B2C
cy.request({
    retryOnStatusCodeFailure: false,
    failOnStatusCode: false,
    url: authority + '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      response_type: 'token id_token',
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: secret,
      scope: ['openid', ...apiScopes].join(' '),
      username,
      password,
    },
    form: true,
  });

This provides valid tokens but the msal library will still not recognize this, as it uses the browser cache to check for valid tokens. You can find a few examples online where this is explained, basically we write the values into the localstorage ourselves, like this shows: https://github.com/juunas11/AzureAdUiTestAutomation/blob/main/UiTestAutomation.Tests/FetchDataTests.cs.
Step 2) Store token into local storage
const idTokenClaims = decode<any>(tokenResponse.id_token);
  const localAccountId = idTokenClaims.oid || idTokenClaims.sid;
  const realm = idTokenClaims.tid || '';
  const flow = idTokenClaims.tfp;
  const homeAccountId = `${localAccountId}-${flow}.${tenantId}`;
  const username = idTokenClaims.name;
  const name = idTokenClaims.name;

  const accountKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment.toLowerCase()}-${realm || '--'}`;
  const accountEntity = buildAccountEntity(homeAccountId, realm, localAccountId, username, name, idTokenClaims);
  localStorage.setItem(accountKey, JSON.stringify(accountEntity));

  const idTokenKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-idtoken-${clientId}-${realm}-`;
  const idTokenEntity = buildIdTokenEntity(homeAccountId, tokenResponse.id_token, realm);

  localStorage.setItem(idTokenKey, JSON.stringify(idTokenEntity));

  const accessTokenKey = `${homeAccountId}-${environment}-accesstoken-${clientId}-${realm}-${apiScopes.join(' ')}`;
  const accessTokenEntity = buildAccessTokenEntity(
    homeAccountId,
    tokenResponse.access_token,
    tokenResponse.expires_in,
    tokenResponse.ext_expires_in,
    realm,
    apiScopes,
  );

  localStorage.setItem(accessTokenKey, JSON.stringify(accessTokenEntity));

Although this is more than suboptimal, it has worked until now (with msal v2), but after updating it it to version 3 it no longer works. With updating to msal v3 we want to get rid of this workaround.
Solution 1 "loadExternalTokens"
In this discussion: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4519 they recommend either using loadExternalTokens which should be a better solution for step 2. However, it is apparently not recommended to be used for E2E testing. From what I understood, we could first perform step 1) and then load the token into the cache doing something like this:
const pca = new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: clientId,
      authority: authority
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    },
  });

  const silentRequest: SilentRequest = {
    scopes: ['openid', apiScopes[0]],
    authority: authority,
  };

  const serverResponse: ExternalTokenResponse = {
    token_type: AuthenticationScheme.BEARER,
    scope: 'openid' + ' ' + apiScopes[0],
    expires_in: Number.parseInt(tokenResponse.expires_in),
    access_token: tokenResponse.access_token,
    id_token: tokenResponse.id_token,
  };

  const loadTokenOptions: LoadTokenOptions = {};

  const msalTokenCache = pca.getTokenCache();
  const res = msalTokenCache.loadExternalTokens(silentRequest, serverResponse, loadTokenOptions);

Unfortunately, when I navigate to my app I still get redirected to the login page, so the msal library does not recognize this as valid logged in user.
Solution 2 "usernamePasswordRequest"
The second recommendation they give is to perform a usernamePasswordRequest for E2E Testing. I tried this with the @msal/azure-node package:
const pca = new PublicClientApplication(config);
const [username, password] = getCredentials();
const usernamePasswordRequest = {
    scopes: ["user.read"],
    username: username,
    password: password,
};

await pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword(usernamePasswordRequest);
tokenCache = pca.getTokenCache().getKVStore();

I then realized that this cannot be done in Cypress, as it relies on NodeJS functionality. The @msal/azure-browser package does not provide this functionality, so I don't know how I could use it in our scenario.
So my questions would be:

How can I get loadExternalTokens to work correctly, so that it recognizes it as being logged in?
Or, how can I make the usernamePasswordRequest work with the @msal/azure-browser package?
Or is it better to completely change the login approach, by - for example - logging in using the UI anyways?

Edit:
I have to edit is because apparently it is a duplicate, which it is not and here is why:
in the related question they use adal I am using msal. Additionally I have tried adding the client_secret which does not change anything, I got the tokens either way.
The problem that I am having is that the msal library does not consider myself being logged in, although I have set every key into the localstorage accordingly.
The error I am getting is:
InteractionRequiredAuthError: interaction_required: AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.
Edit2:
This is the response I am getting when I fetch tokens (as the similar question does).
{
  "body": {
    "access_token": "<removed_sensitive_data>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "refresh_token": "<removed_sensitive_data>",
    "id_token": "<removed_sensitive_data>"
  },
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "set-cookie": [
      "x-ms-cpim-trans=; domain=<removed_sensitive_data>; expires=Sat, 26-Apr-2014 09:30:52 GMT; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly"
    ],
    "x-ms-gateway-requestid": "9b1d2eed-7dec-4515-83bd-fdbe4049c7c3",
    "x-frame-options": "DENY",
    "public": "OPTIONS,TRACE,GET,HEAD,POST",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "allow": "OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST",
    "date": "Fri, 26 Apr 2024 09:30:52 GMT",
    "content-length": "3273"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "isOkStatusCode": true,
  "requestHeaders": {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "content-length": 337
  },
  "requestBody": "grant_type=password&response_type=token%20id_token&client_id=<removed_sensitive_data>&client_secret=<removed_sensitive_data>&scope=openid%20offline_access%20<another_scope>&username=<removed_sensitive_data>&password=<removed_sensitive_data>",
  "duration": 989,
  "allRequestResponses": [
    {
      "Request Body": "grant_type=password&response_type=token%20id_token&client_id=<removed_sensitive_data>&client_secret=<removed_sensitive_data>&scope=openid%20offline_access%20<another_scope>&username=<removed_sensitive_data>&password=<removed_sensitive_data>",
      "Request Headers": {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "content-length": 337
      },
      "Request URL": "https://<removed_sensitive_data>.b2clogin.com/<removed_sensitive_data>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_e2e_testing/oauth2/v2.0/token",
      "Response Body": "{\"access_token\":\"<removed_sensitive_data>\",\"id_token\":\"<removed_sensitive_data>\"}",
      "Response Headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "set-cookie": [
          "x-ms-cpim-trans=; domain=<removed_sensitive_data>.b2clogin.com; expires=Sat, 26-Apr-2014 09:30:52 GMT; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly"
        ],
        "x-ms-gateway-requestid": "9b1d2eed-7dec-4515-83bd-fdbe4049c7c3",
        "x-frame-options": "DENY",
        "public": "OPTIONS,TRACE,GET,HEAD,POST",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "allow": "OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST",
        "date": "Fri, 26 Apr 2024 09:30:52 GMT",
        "content-length": "3273"
      },
      "Response Status": 200
    }
  ]
}


Unfortunately not, this is something I am already doing, which worked with msal v2 but no longer with msal v3.

It looks like you've just missed the client_secret field in cy.request().

I tried this, it does not change anything. I have updated the question.

Voting to re-open, the question is distinct from the previous.

Should you be setting the token in sessionStorage rather than localStorage? (session is mentioned in the error).

In the application I also use localStorage. I just tested it with session storage but without success.

I don't see you using the response from cy.request() - could you add that code?

Updated the question. I added the whole response with all headers. I can reduce it to only the body if that's more readable?
Anyways, as you can see I am getting a 200 status code, so I do infact get tokens. I then store it into the local storage, so I assume something has changed how the tokens are stored, but I am not sure what.

It was the processing of the response I was interested in, I was diffing the code by mikkelmk (claimed to be working) in issue 4519 and noticed you hadn't posted the .then(response => part. I don't know the msal protocol, but I thought a pattern might reveal itself. Using explicit processing with .then(response => might get better results.

Also look at cypress-msal-login, seems reasonably up-to-date.

Thanks, yeah we do it pretty much like the user "mikkelmk" suggested, I have removed the .then(response) part, as the question was already very long.
I also tried the cypress-msal-login package, unfortunately also without success.
For the time being I think we will downgrade to msal v2 again or use interactive login after all (which is not recommended).

I got it work and I am amazed at how many hours I have wasted..
Since I cannot answer this question as it is closed as duplicate I will provide a short answer here. The problem was that my login request was done with some authority B2C_1_e2e_testing but the app used another authority, something like B2C_1_signInSignUp.
